# Play Framework cant create Intellij project

Tags: java, playframework

Ive created a Play Application named Worker (folder and files under it is created).

now im running folowing command to create intellij project from this application:

```
play idealize Worker
```

which returns:

```
play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_40), http://www.playfram
work.com

This is not a play application!

Use `play new` to create a new Play application in the current directory,
or go to an existing application and launch the development console using `play
.

You can also browse the complete documentation at http://www.playframework.com.
```

How to solve this? i already used 2 hours trying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Play! documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/IDE

Since Play framework 2.1 you have to use command in play console:

```
[my_app] $ idea with-sources=yes
```

You can also do without entering play console, running command in terminal:

```
[my_app] $ play "idea with-sources=yes"
```

Just remember that you have to be inside directory of your project.